# Does GridDB Support Data Sharding for Managing Large Datasets

Tags: griddb

I have been utilizing GridDB for storing and managing a steadily growing dataset. As the data volume increases, I am becoming concerned about maintaining performance and ensuring that the data remains easily manageable.

In other database systems I've used, sharding has been a solution to similar concerns. However, I haven’t found detailed information on whether or how sharding can be implemented in GridDB in the [documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/tqlreference/type/#primitive).

My question is,
Does GridDB support data sharding to distribute data across multiple nodes or clusters?
If so, how is sharding configured and managed within GridDB?

Also, are there any best practices or considerations to keep in mind when sharding data in GridDB, especially to ensure balanced load and optimized query performance?